# Running Windows Task Scheduler through Python

Tags: python, windows, scheduled-tasks

I am new to SO. I am given the task of creating a windows task schedule to run a .BAT file using our Python API to push it to our fleet of remote PCs.

I am having issues with passing the arguments over to the `schtask.exe`.

Here is the code:

```
import subprocess
path = "c:\windows\System32\schtasks.exe"
subprocess.Popen([path, "schtasks /create /SC ONLOGON /TN 'Update_Automation_Beta' /TR 'C:\test\run_admin.bat'"], shell = True)
```

Note: The task is just a test task right now, while I try to figure it out. 
Also if typed directly into command prompt window, it will work, removing the quotes etc.

Comment: If you want to use a list, split the entire command line into separate arguments, but don't repeat `schtasks`. And don't use `shell=True`, since there's no reason to run this using cmd.exe.

Comment: Thank you, I did figure it out by doing the following: 
- parsing the code using shlex.split() which made it out to be something like this - '/delete', '/tn', 'update_auto_beta', '/f'
- Removing the schtasks 

thank you

Comment: The command line must already be quoted properly if `shlex.split` works.  On Windows `Popen` has to rebuild the list it into a string for `CreateProcess`, so just pass the command as a string.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call('schtasks /create /SC ONLOGON /TN "Update_Automation_Beta" /TR "C:\test\run_admin.bat"')
```

Use single quotes outside and double qoutes inside. Also you can put in the full path to schtasks, if you need.